# Array con valores repetidos

Tags: javascript, array

estoy intentando armar un arreglo que muestre valores únicos y sumas totales.

Estoy tomando este arreglo que contiene los siguientes valores:

```
[Array]
0: {name: "16", value: "1"}
1: {name: "16", value: "1"}
2: {name: "16", value: "1"}
3: {name: "15", value: "8"}
4: {name: "15", value: "8"}
5: {name: "15", value: "8"}
6: {name: "15", value: "8"}
7: {name: "15", value: "8"}
8: {name: "15", value: "8"}
9: {name: "15", value: "8"}
10: {name: "14", value: "3"}
11: {name: "14", value: "3"}
12: {name: "14", value: "3"}
13: {name: "14", value: "3"}
14: {name: "23", value: "1"}
15: {name: "23", value: "1"}
16: {name: "23", value: "1"}
17: {name: "22", value: "1"}
18: {name: "22", value: "1"}
19: {name: "22", value: "1"}
20: {name: "15", value: "1"}
21: {name: "15", value: "1"}
22: {name: "23", value: "1"}
23: {name: "23", value: "1"}
24: {name: "23", value: "1"}
25: {name: "23", value: "1"}
26: {name: "22", value: "1"}
27: {name: "22", value: "1"}
28: {name: "22", value: "1"}
29: {name: "01", value: "1"}
30: {name: "01", value: "1"}
31: {name: "01", value: "1"}
32: {name: "01", value: "1"}
33: {name: "16", value: "2"}
34: {name: "16", value: "2"}
35: {name: "16", value: "2"}
36: {name: "16", value: "2"}
37: {name: "16", value: "2"}
38: {name: "16", value: "2"}
39: {name: "14", value: "2"}
```

Estoy tratando que quede algo si:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo estoy intentando con siguiente codigo:

```js
public Array2 = [];
var cantidad = 0;
Array.map((i) => {
  if (i.name == i.name) {
    cantidad = cantidad + parseInt(i.value);
    this.Array2.push({
      name: i.name,
      value: i.value,
    });
  }
});
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto me repite los mismo valores de name y me suma mal los values.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se, si existirá alguna forma o algun metodo para representar lo que quiero en el array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Una función reductora (reduce) de una lista, recibe un acumulador, el elemento por el que se está iterando, el índice de ese elemento, y el array original, y le puedes pasar un valor inicial al acumulador.

En nuestro caso solo necesitamos el acumulador y el elemento actual. Comprobamos si en el acumulador existe ya un elemento con el nombre que quieras, si existe, le añades el valor del elemento actual, si no existe, lo creas con el valor del elemento actual.

La función reductora tiene que devolver el acumulador. Todo esto lo puedes ver en el ejemplo de abajo. Al final de la función pasamos un array vacío `[]`, ese es el valor inicial de la función acumuladora.

```js
const valores = [
  {name: "16", value: "1"},
  {name: "16", value: "1"},
  {name: "16", value: "1"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "14", value: "3"},
  {name: "14", value: "3"},
  {name: "14", value: "3"},
  {name: "14", value: "3"},
];

const resumen = valores.reduce((acumulador, elemento) => {
  const elementoEnAcumulador = acumulador.find(el => el.name === elemento.name);
  const valor = parseInt(elemento.value, 10);
  
  if (elementoEnAcumulador) {
    elementoEnAcumulador.value += valor;
  }
  else {
    acumulador.push({ name: elemento.name, value: valor });
  }
  return acumulador;
}, []);

console.log(resumen);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

utilizando array [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) y [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
let valores = [
  {name: "16", value: "1"},
  {name: "16", value: "1"},
  {name: "16", value: "1"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "14", value: "3"},
  {name: "14", value: "3"},
  {name: "14", value: "3"},
  {name: "14", value: "3"},
];

const result = [...valores.reduce((r, o) => {
  const item = r.get(o.name) || Object.assign({}, o, {
    value: 0
  });
  
  item.value += +o.value;
  return r.set(o.name, item);
  
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(result);
```

tambien podrias hacerlo asi:

NOTA: el simbolo + delante de una variable hace un cast equivalente a [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

```js
let valores = [
  {name: "16", value: "1"},
  {name: "16", value: "1"},
  {name: "16", value: "1"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "15", value: "8"},
  {name: "14", value: "3"},
  {name: "14", value: "3"},
  {name: "14", value: "3"},
  {name: "14", value: "3"},
];
var result = [];
 valores.reduce(function(r, o) {
  if (!r[o.name]) {
    r[o.name] = { name: o.name, value: 0 };
    result.push(r[o.name])
  }
  r[o.name].value += +o.value;
  return r;
}, {});
console.log(result)
```